# Limit amount of foreign keys, each one referring to a day of the week

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have two models in my app: Car and CarAvailability.

```
class Car(Model):
    availability = ForeignKey(CarAvailability)
class CarAvailability(Model):
    WEEKDAYS = (
        ('monday', 'Monday'),
        ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('wednesday', 'Wednesday')
        # ... basically all the days of the week
    )
    day = CharField(max_length=20, choices=WEEKDAYS)
```

What are my options to limit the amount of foreign keys (`availability` attribute) to a maximum of 7 and make sure of only one per weekday.
I don't know if I'm making myself clear enough here, let me know if anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve the modeling by using two models `Car` and `DayOfWeek` and model this as a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class DayOfWeek(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    days = models.ManyToManyField(DayOfWeek)
```

an alternative modeling could be to use an integer, and encode it a a "bitstring":

```
from enum import IntFlag

class Day(IntFlag):
    MONDAY = 1
    TUEDAY = 2
    WEDNESDAY = 4
    THURSDAY = 8
    FRIDAY = 16
    SATURDAY = 32
    SUNDAY = 64
```

```
class Car(models.Model):
    days = models.IntegerField()
```

You can then encode this as:

```
Car.object.create(days=Day.MONDAY|Day.FRIDAY)
```

to encode that a car is available on monday and friday.